# Would you use "une" when asked "How many" of a feminine noun?

Tags: genre, nombres

If I asked to buy apples from behind a counter and the seller said "How many?", would I reply *un*, since that is the word for *one*, or would I reply *une*, since the noun is feminine? I believe the answer is *un*, but I suddenly wasn't certain.

Comment: dimitris already gave the correct answer, but let me clarify: *un* and *une* are *both* "the word for one". Like how both *chat* and *chatte* are "the word for cat".

Comment: If you were counting apples aloud, would you count "Une, deux, trois..." ?

Comment: @Aerovistae I think in the case of enumeration both variations are acceptable. Un, deux, trois... ou Une, deux, trois... Pomme is a feminine noun. I don't see any difference with, for instance, étudiantes.

Comment: @Aerovistae Yes, I probably would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one should use une in this context. E.g,

> -- Combien ?
>
> -- J'en voudrais une.

Une is the feminine form of un and agrees in gender with the nom it qualifies.

> Une maison. Vingt et une maisons.

The remaining cardinal numerals adjectives are invariable for *gender*.

Cardinal numbers are used to denote **the day of the month, the year, the title of the king** *(except the first see below)*, the page.

They may also denote acts, scenes, volumes and chapters other than the first (see below).

> page un(e), Henri Quatre, chapitre treize, scène vingt et un, etc.

In all the cases above un (as well as vingt and cent) is invariable.

The ordinal number **premier** is used to denote the first day of the month, the first of a series of kings, emperors and the like of that name, and the first act, scene, chapter, etc.

Le premier mars. François Premier. Chapitre premier. Acte premier. Scène première.

Comment: Note that for kings (and emperors, popes and the likes) "titles", the cardinal *un* is never used and replaced by the ordinal  *premier*.

Comment: @jlliagre Thanks. May be it was not clear, but my reply contains the phrase: "*Cardinal numbers are used to denote the day of the month, the year, the title of the king, the page, etc. (apart from premier=first).*" I should have written it in a better way:-)!

Comment: For the first of their kinds, ordinals are only used for kings (*François premier*, *Élisabeth première*) and days of month (*le premier janvier*). We say *page un* or *page une*, *page deux*..., and *l'année zéro*, *l'an un*, *l'an trois*...

Comment: Ooops! Maintenant j'ai compris:-)! Désolé. Je vais corriger.